Any way to separate objects with the scatter add-on?
Are there any way to separate each objects generated from the scatter add-on?
I'm new to blender so maybe the answer is very obvious, but I've seen no one talk about this online


Select one of the scattered objects and press ⎈ CtrlA to open the Apply menu, and hit Make Instances Real. And if you would like to put them all in a collection, right away you press M to call the Move to Collection operator and select the collection desired.

Thank you so much!

@LisaItsame while commenting thanks on an answer is always appreciated, an even better thing to do on this website is to  upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted. This rewards the authors with points and helps better referencing the answer for anyone trying to find it.
